# XML Serialization leaves file blank after restart

Tags: c#, .net, windows, serialization

We have a problem where our industrial equipments software's .XML settings files become blank, yet they still have the correct number of bytes.

I have a feeling it might be caused by the way the customers are shutting down the PC as it tends to happen after they've down a shutdown, isolate, and boot. The way I save the files is,

1. Serialize to %temp% file
2. Validate that the newly created file starts with <?xml
3. If the /backup folders version of the file is older than a day, copy the existing file to the /backup folder
4. Copy new file to overwrite existing file.

I thought maybe it's related to encoding, disk caching, Windows Update, or Windows Recovery.

Looking for ideas as I've spent two years chasing down why this is happening.

As per request, here is the code.

```cs
        public static bool SerializeObjXml(object Object2Serialize, string FilePath, Type type, bool gzip = false)
        {
            if (!Path.IsPathRooted(FilePath))
                FilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationDir, FilePath);
            bool isSuccess = false;

            var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath));
                        if (gzip)
                        {
                            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                XmlSerializer bf = new XmlSerializer(type);
                                bf.Serialize(ms, Object2Serialize);

                                ms.Position = 0;
                                using (var fileStream = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(tmpFile, FileMode.Create)))
                                {
                                    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream.BaseStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                                    {
                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                                        int numRead;
                                        while ((numRead = ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                                        {
                                            gzipStream.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (!FileChecker.isGZip(tmpFile))
                                throw new XmlException("Failed to write valid XML file " + FilePath);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            using (var fs = new StreamWriter(File.Open(tmpFile, FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                XmlSerializer bf = new XmlSerializer(type);
                                bf.Serialize(fs, Object2Serialize);
                            }
                            if (!FileChecker.isXML(tmpFile))
                                throw new XmlException("Failed to write valid XML file " + FilePath);
                        }
                        isSuccess = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (XmlException)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.DriveNotFoundException) { continue; }
                    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException) { continue; }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) { continue; }
                    catch (System.IO.IOException) { continue; }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (isSuccess)
                {
                    lock (FilePath)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Delete existing .bak file
                            if (File.Exists(FilePath + ".bak"))
                            {
                                File.SetAttributes(FilePath + ".bak", FileAttributes.Normal);
                                File.Delete(FilePath + ".bak");
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }
                        try
                        {
                            //Make copy of file as .bak
                            if (File.Exists(FilePath))
                            {
                                File.SetAttributes(FilePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
                                File.Copy(FilePath, FilePath + ".bak", true);
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }
                        try
                        {
                            //Copy the temp file to the target
                            File.Copy(tmpFile, FilePath, true);
                            //Delete .bak file if no error
                            if (File.Exists(FilePath + ".bak"))
                                File.Delete(FilePath + ".bak");
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    //Delete the %temp% file
                    if (File.Exists(tmpFile))
                        File.Delete(tmpFile);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static class FileChecker
        {
            const string gzipSig = "1F-8B-08";
            static string xmlSig = "EF-BB-BF";// <?x";
            public static bool isGZip(string filepath)
            {
                return FileChecker.CheckSignature(filepath, (3, gzipSig)) != null;
            }
            public static bool isXML(string filepath)
            {
                return FileChecker.CheckSignature(filepath, (3, xmlSig)) != null;
            }
            public static bool isGZipOrXML(string filepath, out bool isGZip, out bool isXML)
            {
                var sig = FileChecker.CheckSignature(filepath, (3, gzipSig), (3, xmlSig));
                isXML = (sig == xmlSig);
                isGZip = (sig == gzipSig);
                return isXML || isGZip;
            }
            public static string CheckSignature(string filepath, params (int signatureSize, string expectedSignature)[] pairs)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
                    throw new ArgumentException("Must specify a filepath");
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pairs[0].expectedSignature))
                    throw new ArgumentException("Must specify a value for the expected file signature");
                int signatureSize = 0;
                foreach (var pair in pairs) 
                    if (pair.signatureSize > signatureSize)
                        signatureSize = pair.signatureSize;
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    if (fs.Length < signatureSize)
                        return null;
                    byte[] signature = new byte[signatureSize];
                    int bytesRequired = signatureSize;
                    int index = 0;
                    while (bytesRequired > 0)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = fs.Read(signature, index, bytesRequired);
                        bytesRequired -= bytesRead;
                        index += bytesRead;
                    }
                    foreach (var pair in pairs)
                    {
                        string actualSignature = BitConverter.ToString(signature, 0, pair.signatureSize);
                        if (actualSignature == pair.expectedSignature)
                            return actualSignature;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi. I have an Idea of why this is likely happening. EG, you are writing nothing to a preexisting file with bytes already allocated on disk resulting in an empty file of N bytes, but you need to post source code for anyone to do anymore than assume. Your question doesn't contain a Minimal Reproduceable Example. Please see this and modify your question so we can assist in answering: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you properly closing the file so it flushes?  Also, disk caching doesn't flush to disk immediately, so improper shutdown (just turning off the system, for example), can leave the file size allocated, but with nulls for all bytes if the actual data hasn't flushed yet.  I've seen scenario many times.

Comment: Have customer open the xml file with notepad and see if the file is really blank.  I think the xml file may have errors and failing reading in program.  There is no way in windows that I can think that a file would end up blank.  There must be corrutped xml inside the file.

Comment: @jdweng I've inspected the files myself with notepad++. They are infact just entirely \0 null characters.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yep, FileStream is closed by the `using(Stream stream){}` I am then opening a new Filestream to examine the first 3 bytes and verify the contents.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins I have added code

Comment: You should not be writing the output file when the data you are writing is empty.  I think the issue is prior to the code posted.  I need to know where the xml data originates.

Comment: Windows does write caching to disk. Even if you close and read back the file, an improper shutdown will leave you will a file filled with nulls, or at least a chunk of the end of the file with  nulls. A tool like Sysinternals Sync can help flush to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Using the operating system's move or copy file to overwrite an existing file is an atomic operation meaning the it wholly succeeds or doesn't and doesn't overlap other file operations.

Therefore what you have should work if that is how you are achieving step 4.

> Copy new file to overwrite existing file.

If instead you are blanking out the existing file and re-writing the data I suspect that could be the the point of failure..

Comment: I've added code to the original answer above. I'm using `File.Copy()` with overwrite `True` for the move operation.

Comment: Could be race condition - e.g. you have `File.Exists()` checks but that could change immediately after that line before running the next line - atomicity for file ops will only be for the single operation..

Answer (score 0):

The issues while file space is being allocated the write is not occurring during shutdown, which leaves you when a file with bytes allocated without the data being flushed to disk.

During the OS shutdown, likely a `ThreadAbortException` is raised which triggers your finally block.

You can attempt to reproduce by calling `Process.Start("shutdown", "-a")` before your return statement but after you have set `success = true`.

I would suggest simplifying your code and have everything run inside of your `try {}` statement. This removes the possibility of having a state where `success = true` before your attempted your write to disk, which is then triggered in a finally statement trigged by a windows shutdown.

```cs
public static bool SerializeObjXml(
    object Object2Serialize, 
    string FilePath, 
    Type type, 
    bool gzip = false)
{

    if (!Path.IsPathRooted(FilePath))
        FilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationDir, FilePath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var tempFi = SerializeToXmlFile(Object2Serialize, type, gzip);
            var fi = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            if (fi.Exists)
                fi.CopyTo(fi.FullName + ".bak", true);
            tempFi.CopyTo(fi.FullName, true);
            tempFi.Delete();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = $"[{DateTime.Now}] Error serializing file {FilePath}. {ex}";
            File.WriteAllText(FilePath + ".log", message);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As a side note, you can simply use `[Stream.CopyTo][1]` and write directly to your temp file, without the need for intermediary streams or for manual buffer/byte read/write operations:

```cs
private static FileInfo SerializeToXmlFile(
    object Object2Serialize,
    Type type,
    bool gzip)
{
    var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    var tempFi = new FileInfo(tmpFile);
    if (!gzip)
    {
        using (var fs = File.Open(tmpFile, FileMode.Create))
            (new XmlSerializer(type)).Serialize(fs, Object2Serialize);
        if (!FileChecker.isXML(tmpFile))
            throw new Exception($"Failed to write valid XML file: {tmpFile}");
    }
    else
    {
        using (var fs = File.Open(tmpFile, FileMode.CreateNew))
        using (var gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress))
            (new XmlSerializer(type)).Serialize(fs, Object2Serialize);

        if (!FileChecker.isGZip(tmpFile))
            throw new Exception($"Failed to write valid XML gz file: {tmpFile}");
    }
    return tempFi;
}
```